# VBA Run-time error '1004' when running on a separate sheet

Tags: excel, vba

When I am on the sheet named "Paste Sheet" the code works as expected. On any other sheet it gives me the Run-time error.

I am unsure as to what I am doing wrong as I am fairly new to VBA.

Calculation Code:
`
Sub Calculations()

```
Dim table As Range, calcTable As Range, nextEmptyCell As Range
Dim name As String, sku As String, inventoryToOrder As Integer
Dim sum As Integer
Dim inStoreInventory As Integer
Dim onlineInventory As Integer
Dim reorderPoint As Integer
Dim rowNum As Integer

Set table = Sheets("Paste Sheet").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))


For Each Row In table.Rows
    name = Row.Cells(1, 7).Value
    sku = Row.Cells(1, 3).Value
    inventoryToOrder = Row.Cells(1, 29).Value
    inStoreInventory = Row.Cells(1, 27).Value
    onlineInventory = Row.Cells(1, 31).Value
    sum = inStoreInventory + onlineInventory
    reorderPoint = Row.Cells(1, 28).Value


    If sum < reorderPoint Then

        Worksheets("Calculations").Range("A2").Value = name
        Worksheets("Calculations").Range("B2").Value = sku
        Worksheets("Calculations").Range("C2").Value = inventoryToOrder
    
    
    End If

Next Row

End Sub
```

`

I am trying to run a simple calculation on a worksheet ("Paste Sheet") and grab certain values like the Name, SKU, and Inventory to Order and paste all of those values in the worksheet called calculations.

The error is preventing me from moving forward and I am unsure how to get around it.

Comment: Add `Sheets("Paste Sheet").` in front of `Range("A2")`,